# React get customhook event in component

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I'm building an UI with a form that appears on a button click.

When I submit the form and that the mutation is over, I want it to close.

However I'm not sure how to do this since my mutation is in a custom hook:

```
export function useCreateContract({ queryKey }) {
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();
  const { enqueueSnackbar } = useSnackbar();

  const { isLoading, mutate } = useMutation({
    mutationFn: ({
      user_id,
      type,
    }) =>
      createContract(
        user_id,
        type,
      ),
    onSuccess: async () => {
      return queryClient
        .invalidateQueries({
          queryKey: queryKey,
        })
        .then(() => {
          enqueueSnackbar("Contract created");
        });
    },
  });

  const createContract = (
    user_id,
    type,
  ) => {
    return axios.post(`/api/contracts`, {
      user_id,
      type,
    });
  };

  return { mutate, isLoading };
}
```

And my form :

```
export function Form({ onCancel, onSuccess }) {
  const { id } = useParams();

  const { mutate, isLoading } = useCreateContract({
    queryKey: ["users", id, "contracts"],
  });
}
```

I wish I could call `onSuccess` when my mutation has succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

Dont try to call side-effects from onSuccess / onError functions ->
https://tkdodo.eu/blog/breaking-react-querys-api-on-purpose

I would handle it this way

Use mutateAsync instead of mutate and wait for the code to finish by listening to finally().

```
 export function Form({ onCancel, onSuccess }) {
  const { id } = useParams();

  const { mutateAsync, isLoading } = useCreateContract({
    queryKey: ["users", id, "contracts"],
  });

  const handleSubmit = async (formValues) => {
    const req = await mutateAsync(formValues).finally(()=> onSuccess())
    
  }
```

}

Comment: This is true for the `useQuery` hook, not the `useMutation`.
However, I will try using `mutateAsync` since it might solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem using `mutateAsync` as mentionned @kapaakinos

This is the code I'm using :

```
export function useCreateContract({ queryKey }) {
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();
  const { enqueueSnackbar } = useSnackbar();

  const { isLoading, mutate, mutateAsync } = useMutation({
    mutationFn: ({
      user_id,
      type,
    }) =>
      createContract(
        user_id,
        type,
      ),
    onSuccess: async () => {
      return queryClient
        .invalidateQueries({
          queryKey: queryKey,
        })
        .then(() => {
          enqueueSnackbar("Contract created");
        });
    },
  });

  const createContract = (
    user_id,
    type,
  ) => {
    return axios.post(`/api/contracts`, {
      user_id,
      type,
    });
  };

  return { mutate, mutateAsync, isLoading };
}
```

Which I use this way in Form:

```
  const { mutateAsync, isLoading } = useCreateContract({
    queryKey: ["users", id, "contracts"],
  });

mutateAsync({
      user_id: parseInt(id),
      type: data.type,
    }).then(() => onSuccess());
```